# Copy a four digit number and past at the end of each line with text before it

Tags: unix, sed

Basically i've been trying to figure out a way to take a four digit number from each line and paste it at the end of its line with the word pass in front. IE

take this file:

```
Home1234 10.10.10.1
Home1248 10.10.10.2 
Home0934 10.10.10.3 
Home0047 10.10.10.4
```

And after should look like:

```
Home1234 10.10.10.1 pass1234
Home1248 10.10.10.2 pass1248
Home0934 10.10.10.3 pass0934
Home0047 10.10.10.4 pass0047
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
awk '{a=substr($1,5,4); print $0" pass"a}' YOUR_FILE
```

- `substr($1,5,4)` gets `NNNN` from `HomeNNNN` and stores in var `a`
- `print $0" pass"a` print all the line plus var `a`

If text is not always `Home` but a different with variable size, you can use:

```
awk '{a=substr($1,length($1)-3,4); print $0" pass"a}' YOUR_FILE
```

Comment: Was updating and generalizing. We thought the same within 30 sec difference!

Answer (score 0):

this awk one-liner may help you:

```
awk '{n=substr($1,length($1)-3);$0=$0" pass"n}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not defined very well (what do you want to do with an input like: `1234 5678 3333 10.3.5.5`?), but perhaps:

```
sed '/^\([^ ]*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*\)/s//\1 pass\2/' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed variation using the & (paste everything matched):

```
sed -ie 's/^.*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/& pass\1/' yourfile
```